# SAX parser: public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length). Value "start" increments too much

Tags: xml, int, character, sax, increment

The SAX parser has this method

```
characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
```

which for what I understand gets the String within the tag. What I realized is that as the SAX parser continues to run on a large XML file, the **int start** becomes bigger and bigger so much so it exceeds the max int value.

I did a print out of **start** and it seems to keep randomly jumping numbers. How is the number determined?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide details of language and library?  It may be a bug in the particular implementation.

Comment: A link to an xml that produces the issue would also be useful.  In quick experimentation, I don't see any evidence of this happening with the standard libraries in Java 1.6.0_51 on MacOS.

Comment: _"so much so it exceeds the max int value"_ -- this isn't possible, of course.  Can you show some evidence?

Answer (score 2):

Typically a SAX parser will read a bufferfull of data at a time. At a given point, a buffer might contain something like this

```
="a" foo="bar"><b x="1">some text</b></a><c
```

Now when the parser is reporting the text node in this buffer, it might make call your ContentHander, supplying a char[] array containing the whole of this buffer, with start=24 length=9. Or if it prefers, it might supply the same data as a sequence of calls. If the text node happens to span two buffers like this:

```
="a" foo="bar"><b x="1">some 
 text</b></a>
```

then the first call might supply the first buffer with start=24 length=4, and the second call would supply the second buffer with start=0 length=5.

The idea is that the parser doesn't have to incur the cost of moving the data out of the original buffer and assembling it into a contiguous string. In theory this gives a performance benefit; in practice, most SAX applications will want to collect the content of a text node into a contiguous string, so the copying cost is simply moved to the application.

Really you shouldn't care what the values of start and length are, or what is in the char[] array outside these bounds. Just copy the data within those bounds to a StringBuilder.